# python-coinmarketcap error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, api, coinmarketcap

I'm working on a trading bot and I pull some information from coinmarketcap using the `python-coinmarketcap` package. It has been working perfectly until yesterday. Now, every time the program reaches the line, it throws this error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError`.

Anybody knows why have this happened? I've tried to read the documentation all day long, but it seems to be unavailable. I write down below some code to replicate the behavior (excluding my API key):

`python-coinmarketcap` and `requests` must be installed from `pip`.

```
import coinmarketcapapi as cmcapi

cmc = cmcapi.CoinMarketCapAPI(config.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY)

cmc.cryptocurrency_listings_latest().data
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you `print`ed `cmc` variable to see whats strored in ?

Comment: I tried debugging it, I have just printed it as you say, but doesn't provide much info :(

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: just executed your code and return json fine for me

Answer (score 0):

try running:

```
cmc.cryptocurrency_listings_latest().status
```

I get:

```
{'timestamp': '2022-06-27T03:17:48.811Z',
 'error_code': 0,
 'error_message': None,
 'elapsed': 19,
 'credit_count': 1,
 'notice': None,
 'total_count': 9924}
```